# Selenium Grid - Is there any way to prevent sharing the clipboard between nodes on several machines?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-grid, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using Selenium Grid with WebDriver, Java, maven and maven-surefire-plugin.

I have 2 machines.

On the first one I have the selenium hub started and 2 nodes.
On the second one I have 2 selenium nodes.

I run the tests with maven, having forkCount=4 in maven-surefire-plugin (one for each node).

Some of the tests are copying content to clipboard, then pasting it somewhere else.

The problem is that the nodes seem to share the same clipboard, so the tests are messed-up.

Is there any solution to prevent the clipboard from being shared between the selenium nodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its the nodes that are sharing the clipboard. I think the clipboard is being shared across test executions because they are being run from the same surefire plugin.

The reason why I say this is because, the nodes are going to be getting only JSONWireProtocol compliant commands. Copying to/from the clipboard is NOT part of the JSONWireProtocol spec and so there is no way the node would be getting requests to access clipboard.

As per the documentation forkCount basically indicates how many JVM processes are to be spawned by surefire to run the tests. What I don't know for sure is, does that cause the JVMs to share the same clipboard or not.

So you might want to consider looking at alternatives to using the clipboard.